# Regexp in the Case of Single and Double Quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, tokenize

I have the following JavaScript:

```
let strTest = `
  "The issue": "L'oggetto ",
  "issue": "oggetto",
  "issue": 'oggetto "novo" ',
  `;
```

I'm trying to tokenize a string like the one above.

My regexp attempt:

```
let regExp = /["'](.*?)["']\s*?:\s*?['"](.*?)["']/gm;
```

This works fine, except in the case where I have a pair of single quotes (') inside of double quotes (") or vice-versa.

Is this possible with only one regular expression?

Comment: *"Can it be possible to do it in only one regexp sentence?"* No, not with JavaScript's regular expressions. You need a more complex parser to handle it correctly.

Comment: so it looks that it can be made in only one single regexp as Rafael Kennedy state ;)

Comment: @ user: No, it can't, not correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my self , I think I came with a smaller regex:

```
` /["'](.*)["']\s*?:\s*?["'[](.*)["']]/g `
```

Have a look at [regex101.com/r/g9WCbi/1](http://regex101.com/r/g9WCbi/1)

Answer (score -1):

You can use backreferences:

```
/(["'])(.*?)\1\s*?:\s*?(['"])(.*?)\3/gm
```

This will include the quotes, in the tokenized string, but you can then remove them from the produced match by taking only the even numbered tokens.

**Edit:**
As @TJ Crowder points out, this will not work correctly if the string contains escaped quotes in the form of `\"` within the string. In order to completely accommodate those escaped quotes and not break on strings like `\\"`(an escaped backslash preceding a quote) you will need to parse with multiple regexes or take a different tactic

The other thing you might want to look at, if this is coming from JSON, is ignoring regex, and just iterating through the properties of your json object. It depends if the string you're getting is coming in as valid json or not.

Comment: This is exactly what I need :) thanks  Rafael Kennedy

Comment: @user2521616: Beware that this doesn't handle escaped quotes correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/bkkcyy8L/ Which is why it can't be done in a single regex with JavaScripts' regex engine. If you try to handle escaped quotes, you can get to the point where it seems to work, and then fails on an escaped backslash prior to a quote. Etc.

Comment: Fair enough. It depends on how that string is being generated if that's an issue in this particular case, but a good point.

Comment: How about `/
(['"])(?:|(.+?[^\\](?:(?:\\\\)+|[^\\])))\1\s*:\s*(['"])(?:|(.+?[^\\](?:(?:\\\\)+|[^\\])))\3/g`

Comment: I think I came with a smaller regex: 
  `   /["'](.*)["']\s*?:\s*?["'\[](.*)["'\]]/g  `
Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/g9WCbi/1